# Get the selected value from Laravel Form::select using vue.js

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js

How can I get the value of the selected item from Laravel 5.3 `Form::select()` using vue.js. I have been using Laravel 5.1 and AngularJS but I am starting a new project with Laravel 5.3 so I decided to use vue.js. With Angular I used this:

```
{!! Form::select('status',Status(),NULL, ['class' => 'form-control','ng-model'=>'status','placeholder'=>'All Status','ng-change'=>'getStatus(status)','ng-init'=>"getStatus(100)"]) !!}
```

Then in my AngularJS file I write the method `getStatus` that tracks the changes and returns the newly selected item.

I am very new to vue.js and I have no idea how to do the same. I have tried using `v-model` but I get errors

**Update**
This form is inside a `foreach` loop in blade and when I use `v-model` it only works for the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in angular js ,you can use the event object to get the value like this,

`v-on:change="getStatus(event)"`

and from the $event object you can get the value like this,

```
var a=event.target.value;
```